# Regex for Doesnt Contain occurance of

Tags: regex

Looking for help with a regex statement.

I have a list of files called

```
icn_home.png
icn_home@2x.png
icn_home@3x.png
```

Im looking for regex which will only accept values which do not end with     `@2x.png`.

Im then going to run a script which deletes all the remain files. So the `.png` and`.png@3x` will be deleted, leaving on the `@2x.png` files

Comment: Which language/tool and what have you tried?

Comment: Note that depending on the tool, you could just invert the match for a simpler regex. So if you can use `grep`, you could do this: `ls -1 | grep -v "@2x\.png$"`, where `-v` inverts the match.

Comment: getting -bash: !.*@2x\.png$: event not found

Comment: @JWalker1995: You should tag your question with `bash`. If using `bash` then use `grep -v "@2x\.png$" file`

Comment: @JWalker1995, that error is from bash, not the regex. It's related to history substitution. The regex looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Does not end with `@2x.png`:

```
^(?!.*@2x\.png$)
```

---

- `^` - from the start of the string
- `(?!)` - a negative lookahead
- `.*` - any amount of characters
- `\.` - the dot has to be escaped, otherwise it means *any character*
- `$` - end of string

Comment: getting -bash: !.*@2x\.png$: event not found

Comment: @JWalker1995, you didn't say what language you are using. Specify that with a tag.

Answer (score 1):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?!.*@2x\.png$).+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9ITd6D32Xh0qKyw_)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hW0eZ4/1)